# Reload page in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, reload

I'm just starting with angular 2. I have a problem with page reload. After page load complete, i navigate to another page and pressed back button,page auto reload. Anybody help me, how to prevent it?

Comment: After clicking back button, what happened? and what you need?

Comment: i need that page does not reload again because it loaded complete first when i start web

Comment: make it clear, on clicking back button which pages reload? the already loaded page or the last page? explain clearly, do not mix things!

Comment: okay, let me explain clearly for you understand. When i start my website, it have Homepage include navigation bar. And i click navigation bar navigate  to Second page then click back button, homepage reload again. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use router-outlet to configure your states, so that the page wont get refreshed.

**`Angular Router`** enables navigation from one view to the next as users perform application tasks.

Read more on **[`Routing and Navigation`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)**

Comment: Thank for your support, but all data i get from server, it's not on local. I tried with local data, it run normal

Comment: it does not matter where you get the data from

Comment: i dont know why, but when i do with local data, it dont have a problem

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
       {path: '', component: HomepageComponent},
       {path: 'tintuc/:category', component: 
    TrangTinTongHopComponent},
       {path: 'noidung/:route/:id/:title', component: 
    TrangNoiDungComponent},
       {path: 'hoidap', component: TrangHoiDapComponent},
       {path: 'trangnguoidung', component: 
    TrangNguoiDungComponent},
       {path: 'tracuudiemthi', component: TrangXemDiemComponent}

     ];
     @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
      })

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your RouterModule like,

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        MenuComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        RegistrationComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // MUST BE FIRST IMPORT. THIS AUTOMATICALLY IMPORTS BROWSERMODULE, HTTPMODULE, AND JSONPMODULE TOO.
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ]
})
```

And added    in the app.component like

```
<div class='row'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And the like for router-outlet look like,

```
<div class='main-nav'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
        <div class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]="['/home']">
                         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Logo
                    </a>
                </li> 
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/login']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-Tab1'></span> Login
                    </a>
                </li> 
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/registration']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-Tab2'></span> Register
                    </a>
                </li> 
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/Tab3']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-Tab3'></span> Tab3
                    </a>
                </li> 
            </ul>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thank for your support, but my code is the same, just different that i binding data from server to generate navigation bar